# How to count occurrences of each distinct value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently pull a list of distinct 'tags' (lowercased) from my DB with the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LOWER(tag)) AS tag FROM user.tags ORDER BY LOWER(tag);
```

I want to add a second column to my results which counts the number of occurrences of each tag. So instead of getting back:

```
tag:
'test'
'sample'
'example'
```

I would get:

```
tag:      count:
'test'      3
'sample'    2
'example'   7
```

Comment: Do some research on `group by` and `count()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LOWER(tag), COUNT(1) AS tag 
FROM user.tags 
GROUP BY LOWER(tag) 
--ORDER BY COUNT(1); -- if you want to order by the count
```